# If + would clause?

Tags: sentence-construction

I've found this sentence and its construction confused me

> *If you only would be* as amazing as everyone else around you obviously is — people who are leading these incredibly interesting, smart, connected and on-the-edge lives — you would be invited to TED, to speak at Summit, have a million followers and basically be worth writing about, too.

What does that mean? What kind of sentence structure is that?

Comment: It's just typical American poor speech. "If only you were as amazing" is much better. Americans are doing If + would a lot more these days but it marks the speaker. Highly educated speakers do not use it....It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think there is any justification for branding this particular form of "poor speech" as American or to imply that Americans are not "highly educated speakers." This is offensive.

Comment: @TypeIA I am American, and a native speaker and I say it is: I would see him if I would go. T-E-R-R-I-B-L-E.Most Americans are not very educated speech-wise.

Comment: https://www.lawlessenglish.com/english-mistakes/if-i-would-have/https://www.lawlessenglish.com/english-mistakes/if-i-would-have/ You hear it on the radio, on TV from uneducated speakers. That's the truth.

Comment: I'm also American (expat) and a native speaker. I can't make things true by saying that they are. But I see no evidence to support this being a "typical American" error. And divergent American (or British, Indian, etc.) speech patterns are not necessarily indicative of poor education.

Comment: @TypeIA Though I listen to tons of BrE on the TV and radio, I have not heard this particular thing as often as on US TV and radio. So, I daren't speak for BrE  speakers in this case. Here is the quote: http://www.robbsmith.com/you-re-not-special-and-that-s-good Different patterns of English have nothing to do with this. This is not a sociolect or variety of English, it''s just bad English, especially for someone who says "me, me,me" in another form: http://www.robbsmith.com/bio

Comment: If this were a sociolect, that would be fine. It isn't and sticks out like a sore thumb.